# jpa Entity Metadata

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a generic solution whenever a JPA entity is deleted.I have confiugred a EntityListener class and my @PreRemove method is invoked before the entity is deleted.

I need to know the table name and primary key column of this entity . Is there a generic way to get this meta data from the Entity object ?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945041/retrieving-jpa-entity-list-and-metadata

Comment: Thanks for the link. In my case the entitylistener is a pojoclass . For eg : @EntityListeners(MyAuditListener.class). In the Pojo class I do not have reference to the EntiyManager . Is there a way to get the reference to EntityManager from the EntityClass

Answer (score 0):

Using hibernate envers looks like I am closer to solving this .