# how to get alias name in Spring boot

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

how to get alias name using spring-data-jpa in Spring boot?
I want alias name for stored procedure

```
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entitymanager.createStoredProcedureQuery(Proc);

        if (params != null && params.length > 0) { // If no parameters supplied then no need to add it
            int paramCount = 0;
            for (String param : params) {
                paramCount++;
                storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(paramCount, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
                storedProcedure.setParameter(paramCount, param);
                // System.out.println("param" +param); 
            }

        }
        List<Object[]> storedProcedureResults = storedProcedure.getResultList();
```

this will return me only result but i also want column name which i have given in stored procedure

Comment: What alias do you want? Can you show the stored procedure and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Simon from above code i will get only records which are returned by stored procedure . But i also want the column name.

Comment: That's not possible with JPA

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945041/retrieving-jpa-entity-list-and-metadata